# OpenGL ES 2.0 plane morph/distortion effect GPUImage iOS

Tags: ios, image-processing, opengl-es-2.0, depth-buffer, gpuimage

was playing a bit with awesome GPUImage framework and was able to reproduce some "convex"-like effects with fragment shaders.

However, I'm wondering if it's possible to get some more complex plane curving in 3D using GPUImage or any other OpenGL rendering to texture.

The effect I'm trying to reach looks like this one - is there any chance I can get something alike using depth buffer and vertex shader - or just need to develop some more sophisticated fragment shader emulating Z coordinate?

[image: Live camera output - it's the plain sheet of paper]

This is what I get now using only fragment shader and some periodical bulging
[image: Here is what I could get with fragment shader in GPUImage - not that cool]

Thanks

Well another one thought is maybe it's possible to prototype a curved surface in some 3d modeling app and somehow map the texture to it?

Comment: Try giving us a hint on what do you really want to archive. This effect is probably easier to accomplish by just using a mesh and apply your deformations to it than write a large per fragment code.

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I've project in university where I aim to get effects similar to Photo Booth app - e.g. applying some distortions to live camera output - this is the example of what I'd like to achieve. I think mesh is OK but I have no idea how to design it and apply to the texture?